# Member Access Features in Polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

```java
public class A {
    public int a = 10;
    public void show() {

    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public int a = 20;
    public int b = 10;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        System.out.println(this.a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.show();
        System.out.println(a.a);
    }
}
```

See the code above, I use parent `class A` references to point to the child `class B object (A a = new B())`, But when I print `a.a(System.out.println(a.a))` in the main method, it prints `10` because the member variable a is assigned a value of `10` in the parent `class A`. But when I print `this.a(System.out.println(this.a))` in the `show` method, which is rewritten in the subclass, the `show` method prints `this.a (System.out.println(this.a))`, it prints `20` and I'm confused. I think the result should be the same.
You can see the output as shown below：

```
20
10
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: class A() , class does not has ```()``` around it

Comment: Yes, I have modified it.

Answer (score 0):

In java only methods are overridden, not variables. So, parent classe's variables won't be overridden by child's classes variable. It's a design decision in java. And one of the concern is that the parent classes methods can perform without worrying about child's classes variables...i.e. it helps in `not breaking parent classes code`...

An example could be like below:

```
public class Parent {
  String someVar; // note this: it is "String" type
  String getSomeVar() {
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  int someVar; // same name but different type, this would break the code if
  // java permit "variable overriding" feature
}
```

You can clearly see that parent's type and child's type are different. I guess, you can understand now why variable overriding would be dangerous...

**Update:**

@helloWorld, After reading the last comment you've made, it looks like, you're misunderstanding the idea of `overriding`.

Specially, I've prepared an example for you. Read the following code with comments:

```
class A {
    public int a = 10;

    public void show () {
        System.out.println("Inside A: " + this.a);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public int a = 20;
    public int b = 10;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Inside B: " + this.a);
    }
}
```

```
B b = new B();
A a = b;

b.show(); // prints "Inside B: 20", it should print "20", so it's okay
a.show(); // prints "Inside B: 20", so, method in 'A' is overrided by class 'B', cause, in normal definition it should print "10"

System.out.println("value of b.a: " + b.a); // prints "value of b.a: 20", it should print '20', so it's okay
System.out.println("value of a.a: " + a.a); // prints "value of a.a: 10", it is not overrided by class 'B', but notice 'a.show()' method was overrided
```

So, I guess, you've understood, that overriding means: when use `something(a method/variable)` by `parent/super class's reference` but get the behavior defined in `child class's` while `parent/super` class's implementation of that `particular method/variable` is present, is known as overriding...

You may also read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

And about `this`:

`this` is bound to `an object`. And it's always used to `access` only that particular `class's scope` i.e. the `variables/methods` declared in that `class`. So, to access `parent` within `child` you need to use `super`.

Comment: I know only method are overridden, not variables in java.In other words, i think variable a in class A  has nothing to do with variable a in B.But when i use method show (`System.out.println(this.a)`)  in main,I think 'this' shoud be reference to object a of parent class A.So here should print 10 not 20.

Comment: @helloWorld, No, as the method is overridden, the passed `this` would use `B` classes `a` variable...but of course you have already got it...you can access `A`'s `a` variable using `super`...hope it clears things up...

Comment: @reyadThank you very much.I probably understand what you mean，But I'm still a little confused.Because in `A a = new B()`,I think a should use variable `a` in class A not in class B.In method main,you could see  `System.out.println(a.a)` will  print 10(`public int a = 10` in class a).

Comment: @helloWorld, tell me `what is this pointer`...which object `this` pointer targets...in a overrided method scope `this` pointer targets the `child` and `this` exists only in `non-static` methods...so, `a` may be casted to `A` but it is created using `B`... that's how `java` resolves the problem of targeting proper variable in `parent scope` and `child scope`...that's how java works...now we can't change it...it's java's philosophy...its what java do..:D

Comment: ,well,thank you again.Maybe the way I use violate java's philosophy, I think I should give up the way to avoid Unnecessary trouble.

Comment: Today I read again the answer you gave about why variables can't be overridden.If `String someVar` in parent class can be overridden by `int someVar` in child class.When a subclass object（`Child c = new Child()`） calls the getSomeVar method,the method will return a int variable(Assuming variables can be overridden),but  the return value type of `getSomeVar` is String.

Comment: @helloWorld, I guess, the discussion would clear your mind...take a look...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best practice for Polymorphism is not by overriding the variable, because it will cause a fatal error. If your question is about "Polymorphism: how-to," this answer may help:

```
    //create class A, as you did:
    public class A {
        public int a; //note that we do not initialize the value here
        public void show() {
    
        }
    }

    //extend class B from class A, as you did:
    public class B extends A {
        public int b; //note that we only need to declare variable b

        @Override
        public void show() {
            System.out.println(this.a);
        }
    }

    //in the main class:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B a = new B();
        a.a = 20;
        a.b = 10;
        a.show();
    }
```